Kurtosis of b(n,p) - binomial distribution
So I have this problem that I’m trying to do.
I been at this for hours.
It’s to find the kurtosis of a binomial distribution.
So far, I have that M’’’’(0) = $n[(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)p^4 + 6(n-1)(n-2)p^3 +7(n-1)p^2 + p]$
Then for $\frac{E(X^4) - 4\mu E(X^3) + 6\mu^2 E(X^2) - 4\mu^3 E(X) + \mu^4}{\sigma^4} =$
$\frac{n[(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)p^4 + 6(n-1)(n-2)p^3 +7(n-1)p^2 + p] - 4(n[(n-1)(n-2)p^3 +3(n-1)p^2 + p + 6(np)^2(np + n(n-1)p^2 - 4(np)^3 + (np)^4}{(\sqrt{np(1-p)})^4} =$
From there I can’t seem to get $\frac{1-6(1-p)}{np(1-p)}$.
I know it’s all simplification and that but I can’t seem to get it right.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you dealing with the raw kurtosis or the excess kutosis? Wikipedia suggests the 4th central moment of a binomial distribution is $npq(1+(3n-6)pq)$ and that leads to a raw kurtosis of $3+ \frac{1-6pq}{npq}$

cross posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4948592/excess-kurtosis-of-binomial-distribution

If you're not constrained in what method you use, I'd probably have started with an expression for the factorial moments. It might simplify things a bit.

Why not start with the fact that the binomial distribution is the distribution of the sum of iid Bernoulli's?
